# Django server stops on multiple requests

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django server with ORM for my backend. When I am running multiple requests in parallel the Django server stops at `execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)` in manage.py. I can't get actual exception. If anybody knows how to solve, help me.

Comment: on what os?  what python ? venv ? django ver ?

Comment: I am using  Windows Server 2016, Django 3.0.8, Python 3.7